Why does my Vercel serverless function fail to read request headers in production?
I am working on a Vercel project with both a local development environment (using vercel dev) and a production environment deployed on Vercel's serverless platform.
I need to send credentials (email, pwd, and id) via request headers in a GET request. This works perfectly in my local environment, but in production, I get the following error:
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at module.exports (/var/task/api/user/user.js:16:16)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:2:11027)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:9:6760)

The error occurs here:
  let email, pwd, userId;

  try {
    email = req.body.email || req.headers["email"] || req.headers?.email || null;
    pwd = req.body.pwd || req.headers["pwd"] || req.headers?.pwd || null;
    userId = req.body.participantId || req.headers["id"] || req.headers?.id || null;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error parsing input:", err);
    return res.status(400).json("Bad Request");
  }

Client side GET-request:
axios.get(`/api/user/user/`, {headers: { "email": email, "pwd": pwd, id: participantId }}, { withCredentials: true })
                    .then((res) => res.data.fullName)
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return "Error loading participant";
                    })

Debugging steps I tried:

Logging req.headers both locally and in prod 

I see email, pwd and id both with the correct value


I ensured header names were case-insensitive in the serverless function
Verified that Axios is sending headers correctly

Observations:

The headers are being sent to the backend
In prod the serverless function cant access them for some reason
Locally in the dev enviornment it works without problems

Questions:

Why does the serverless function fail to read headers in production?
Is there a known issue with Vercel's serverless environment
stripping certain headers?
How can I ensure the headers (email, pwd,
id) are properly passed and read in production?

Thanks in advance I appriciate your help
